# React Native release build doesn't load ahead of the splash screen

Tags: react-native

The RN android app is not loading after the splash screen in the release build. While in the debug mode, it works fine.

Here is [ADB LOG FILE](http://pasted.co/2cf6e5d8) from 08-20 00:16:55 (App is opened) to 08-20 00:17:17. There isn't any error here that can actually cause the app to hang.

Please suggest how to go ahead and solve this issue. Really frustrating.

`package.json`

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "es6-symbol": "^3.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.3.0",
    "mobx": "^5.0.3",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.3",
    "npm": "^6.4.0",
    "nt-transmit-transparently": "^1.0.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-app-intro": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-cached-image": "^1.4.3",
    "react-native-contacts": "^2.2.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.10.2",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-firebase-analytics": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.10.14",
    "react-native-google-maps-directions": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.0.16",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.0.16",
    "react-native-interactable": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.19.0",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-modal-wrapper": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-phone-input": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box": "2.3.2",
    "react-native-radial-gradient": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-responsive-image": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.32",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-share": "^1.0.24",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6",
    "react-native-storage": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-text-ticker": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.1",
    "recyclerlistview": "^1.2.2",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "regenerator": "^0.13.2",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.1",
    "url-parse": "^1.4.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^3.9.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.0.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "jsc-android": "^224109.1.0"
  }
}
```

React Native Environment Info:

```
    System:
      OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5557U CPU @ 3.10GHz
      Memory: 117.93 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.2.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.2.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 11.1, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11.1, watchOS 4.1
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 2.3 AI-162.4069837
      Xcode: 9.1/9B55 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1 
      react-native: ^0.56.0 => 0.56.0 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
      react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
      react-native-rename: 2.1.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED. Seems like the issue was with hiding the Splashscreens.

Comment: Hi, facing a similar issue here. Can you please describe how you solved?

Comment: SplashScreen.hide() may be